# How to avoid that Bootstrap modal blocks all asp buttons inside or outside of modal, whether modal is shown or not

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Asp.net 4.5 web form with masterpage, a listview and some asp buttons for different tasks, then a html button to trigger modal. Modal pops up looking good. No other buttons work. Asp button on modal does not fire event either.
I removed the modal div and everything worked fine. 
I think that the modal has some sort of listening function that might intercept all other events, could that be the problem? The old ajax toolbox modal popup did not pose this problem.
Anyone know how I can fix this? The modal is really well suited for the user interaction, I hope I can get it to work.

EDIT: asp button event on modal does work. It's outside, when modal is not shown, that is the problem.

This is the top of my page form with btnEmpty that does not work:

Send bestilling

### <%: Page.Title %>

```
<p class="text-danger">
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ErrorMessage" />
</p>
<br/>
<div class="row">
    <section>
        <asp:ListView ID="lvHandleliste" runat="server"
            OnItemDataBound="lvHandleliste_ItemDataBound"
            OnDataBound="lvHandleliste_DataBound"
            EmptyDataText="Handlekurven er tom">
```

And this is the modal, it's put in the very bottom of the page contentplaceholder:

```
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" style="padding:20px 50px;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h2 class="modal-title">Bestillingsinformasjon</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="tbxBestillingsnr">Bestillingsnr </label>
          <asp:TextBox ID="tbxBestillingsnr" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbxBestillingsnr" Display="Dynamic"
              CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="" Text="Fyll ut!" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="tbxReferanse">Vår ref </label>
          <asp:TextBox ID="tbxReferanse" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbxReferanse" Display="Dynamic"
              CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="" Text="Fyll ut!" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="tbxAdresse">Leveringsadresse </label>
          <asp:TextBox ID="tbxAdresse" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="4" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbxAdresse" Display="Dynamic"
              CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="" Text="Fyll ut!" />
        </div>

        <asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Send bestilling" CssClass="btn btn-info btn-block" OnClick="btnSend_Click" />

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer" style="padding:20px 50px;">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Avbryt</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No response to my question but I finally found the answer myself. Here goes:
In my modal body I have some RequiredFieldValidators. These acted on all submit buttons on the page. So when the modal was hidden no submit could be done since the control fields required were not filled in. 
The solution is to add all validator controls to a validation group, together with the one submit button their supposed to act on. Easy :-)

Hope this helps other people,
Siw